# Mismatching symbol size in cases environment with acronym package

Tags: math-mode, acronyms, cases

I'm running into trouble using the acronym package when I set math formulas in the cases environment. Looking at the following MWE, you will notice that inside the arccot "gamma" and "p" are smaller than the clickable "a" and "y" whereas outside, y and gamma are sized correctly. I've traced the problem down to the cases environment, but have no idea how to fix it. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        \text{arccot}\left(\frac{\gamma{}^2-\acs{a}\cdot\acs{y}}{p}\right) & \acs{y}<=|\gamma{}|
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{a}[\ensuremath{a}]{half width of the superconducting strip}
    \acro{y}[\ensuremath{y}]{cartesian coordinate}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Rendered MWE: [image: MWE]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd never use the `acronym` package for a mathematical symbol, but, as David Carlisle often says in chat, “the customer's always right”.

The problem is that `\acs` uses `\mbox`, which explains the problem. Here's a patch:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%% make \acs use \text instead of \mbox
\patchcmd{\AC@acs}{\mbox}{\text}{}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\arccot\left(\frac{\gamma^{2}-\acs{a}\cdot\acs{y}}{p}\right) & \acs{y}\le|\gamma|
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{a}[\ensuremath{a}]{half width of the superconducting strip}
    \acro{y}[\ensuremath{y}]{cartesian coordinate}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\DeclareMathOperator` should be used for “arccot”. Note also that `\gamma{}^2` is wrong and the `{}` should be omitted. There's no problem with spaces in math mode (they're essentially ignored) so the trick used for macros in normal text is not to be used: compare the result of `$\Gamma{}_{2}$` and `$\Gamma_{2}$` to see why. Note also `\le` instead of `<=` that's not proper mathematical notation.

[image]